# How to troubleshoot message=Request method 'POST' not supported as "application/json"

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot application that allows the user to save documents to the sever that they create and edit through Tinymce.

But when I click the save button I get this error regarding POST:

```
Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

...

```
Request method 'POST' not supported

status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/docs}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

From my Controller for Docs

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/html", consumes={"application/json","application/xml"} )
    public String addTodos(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

        docsService.addDocs(name);

        return "200 OK";
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces="text/html", consumes = {"application/json","application/xml"})
    public String updateComplated(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

        docsService.updateComplated(name);

        return "200 OK";
    }
```

What I do not understand about this error is that I clearly specify how to handle the POST method, yet it says it does not exist.

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot this?

Here is a screenshot from Firefox developer tools showing Response and Request headers

[image]

The params look like this:
[image: Params]

Comment: What's the URI you are hitting for `POST`ing? You should use a "fixed" URI for `HTTP POST`, it makes no sense to be "dynamic", otherwise your resource(s) representation is (going to be) awkward.

Comment: are you hitting `/docs` and not `/name`? Because thats in your message: `message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/docs}`

Comment: Yes, @Patrick it is hitting /docs and not name. name is supposed to be passed into my DocsService and DocsServiceImplementation classes.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ it is hitting /docs. Should I just make value=/docs in RequestMapping ? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: So based on @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ 's feedback, i have made some progress. using {name} was a poor idea and it is easier using a fixed URI. I am using RequestBody with name as a String variable ... making progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, didn't expect to figure this out but here it is.

First, I instead set up a "fixed" URI for HTTP POST. I just took out the value portion of the RequestMapping.

Second, as I took out the value section of RequestMapping, I also took out the @PathVariable. Instead as you see, I pointed @RequestBody at String name, and then specified the target entity.

After doing this, I received a 415 error instead of a 405. This means that the POST method was recognized, but the mediatype was incorrect. Despite what you may read in other posts, you can keep @RequetBody in and specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` as the content type to be consumed.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html", consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})
    public String handle(@RequestBody String name, Docs docs) {

        docsService.addDocs(name);

        return "200 OK";

    }
```

FYI this took me hours upon hours to fix. Hope the answer helps.